# Check if a field is an integer in awk

Tags: awk

I am using the following script to find the number of running connections on my mongodb-server.

```
mongostat | awk 'BEGIN{FS=" *"}{print "Number of connections: "$19}'
```

But every 10 lines, $19 carries a string, denoting a field name.

I want to modify my script to print only if `$19` is an integer.

I could try `FS = " *[^0-9]*"`, but it matches columns that start with number rather than giving selective printing.

Comment: And on the eighth day god invented perl.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use

```
mongostat | awk -F ' *' '$19 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ { print "Number of connections: " $19 }'
```

`$19 ~ /^[0-9]+$/` checks if `$19` matches the regex `^[0-9]+$` (i.e., if it only consists of digits), and the associated action is only executed if this is the case.

By the way, come to think of it, the special field separator is probably unnecessary. The default field separator of `awk` is any sequence of whitespaces, so unless `mongostat` uses an odd mix of tabs and spaces,

```
mongostat | awk '$19 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ { print "Number of connections: " $19 }'
```

should work fine.

Comment: The second thing you gave, without the special field separator, doesn't work for some reason. Rest all is awesome. Peace yo!

Comment: That's odd, but since I'd have to install MongoDB to check it out, I'll chalk it up as a mystery. If there's a stray tab between spaces in the output, that would be parsed as a field with `-F ' *'` but not with the default `FS`, so probably something along those lines is happening.

Comment: Bracket expressions also work: `$19 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/`.

Comment: gives false negative on numbers in scientific notation. Because awk in fact does parse scientific notation and allows arithmetic with it.

Comment: This is probably not the best answer of those now posted.  _"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems."_

Answer (score 11):

You have to be very careful here. The answer is not as simple as you imagine:

- an integer has a sign, so you need to take this into account in your tests. So the integers `-123` and `+123` will not be recognised as integers in earlier proposed tests.
- awk flexibly converts variables types from floats (numbers) to strings and vice versa. Converting to strings is done using `sprintf`. If the float represents an integer, use the format `%d` otherwise use the format `CONVFMT` (default `%.6g`). Some more detailed explanations are at the bottom of this post. So checking if a number is an integer or if a string is an integer are two different things.

So when you make use of a regular expression to test if a number is an integer, it will work flawlessly if your variable is still considered to be a string (such as an unprocessed field). However, if your variable is a number, awk will first convert the number in a string before doing the regular expression test and as such, this can fail:

```
is_integer(x) { x ~ /^[-+]?[0-9]+$/ }
BEGIN { n=split("+0 -123 +123.0 1.0000001",a)
        for(i=1;i<=n;++i) print a[i],is_integer(a[i]), is_integer(a[i]+0), a[i]+0
}
```

which outputs:

```
+0          1          1        0
-123        1          1        -123
+123.0      0          1        123        << QUESTIONABLE
1.0000001   0          1        1          << FAIL
            ^          ^
          test        test
        as string   as number
```

As you see, the last case failed because "%.6g" converts `1.0000001` into the string `1` and this is done because we use string operations.

A more generic solution to validate if a variable represents an integer would be the following:

```
function is_number(x)   { return x+0 == x }
function is_string(x)   { return ! is_number(x) }
function is_float(x)    { return x+0 == x && int(x) != x } 
function is_integer(x)  { return x+0 == x && int(x) == x } 
BEGIN { n=split( "0 +0 -0 123 +123 -123 0.0 +0.0 -0.0 123.0 +123.0 -123.0  1.23 1.0000001 -1.23E01 123ABD STRING",a)
    for(i=1;i<=n;++i) {
        print a[i], is_number(a[i]), is_float(a[i]), is_integer(a[i]), \
              a[i]+0, is_number(a[i]+0), is_float(a[i]+0), is_integer(a[i]+0)
    }
}
```

This method still has issues with recognising `123.0` as a float, but that is because awk only knows floating point numbers.

---

> A numeric value that is exactly equal to the value of an integer (see Concepts Derived from the ISO C Standard) shall be converted to a string by the equivalent of a call to the `sprintf` function (see String Functions) with the string `"%d"` as the `fmt` argument and the numeric value being converted as the first and only `expr` argument. Any other numeric value shall be converted to a string by the equivalent of a call to the `sprintf` function with the value of the variable `CONVFMT` as the `fmt` argument and the numeric value being converted as the first and only `expr` argument. The result of the conversion is unspecified if the value of `CONVFMT` is not a floating-point format specification. This volume of POSIX.1-2017 specifies no explicit conversions between numbers and strings. An application can force an expression to be treated as a number by adding zero to it, or can force it to be treated as a string by concatenating the null string ( `""` ) to it.
>
> **<sub>source: [Awk Posix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)</sub>**

Comment: These "more generic solutions" s/b the accepted answer (I understand it was posted long after the OP and originally-accepted result -- just want to draw attention to them as better solutions for future visitors).

Answer (score 10):

Check if this field is formed by just digits by making it match the regex `^[0-9]+$`:

```
$19~/^[0-9]+$/
```

`^` stands for beginning of string and `$` for end, so we are checking if it consist in digits from the beginning until the end. With `+` we make it match at least one digit, otherwise an empty field would also match (so a file with less fields would always match).

All together:

```
mongostat | awk 'BEGIN{FS=" *"} $19~/^[0-9]+$/ {print "Number of connections: "$19}'
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know how to add a condition after I match.

Comment: Good to know! Note also you may want to use Wintermute's suggestions (I was about to comment them as well, but don't want to have verbatim solutions)

Comment: The regex explanation was unnecessary. :P I just needed awk help. But, thanks anyways.

Comment: OK, note also you may want to say `print "Number of connections:", $19`. That is, let awk itself print the space.